# R - Create a separate environment where to source() an R script, such that the latter does not affect the "caller" environment

Tags: r, pipeline, environment

**Scenario:**  Let's say I have a master `pipeline.R` script as follows:

```
WORKINGDIR="my/master/dir" 
setwd(WORKINDIR)

# Step 1
tA = Sys.time()
source("step1.R")
difftime(Sys.time(), tA)

# Add as many steps as desired, ...
```

And suppose that, within `step1.R` happens a:

```
rm(list=ls())
```

**Question**: 
How can I *separate* the `pipeline.R` (caller) environment from the `step1.R` environment? 
More specifically, I would like to run `step1.R` in separate environment such that any code within it, like the `rm`, does not affect the caller environment.

Comment: you could create an enviornmenti.e. `e1 <- new.env()` and then source it to that enviornment i.e. `sys.source("step1.R", envir=e1)`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `source`, especially its `local` argument? Looks like it could do what you want. ("TRUE, FALSE or an environment, determining where the parsed expressions are evaluated. FALSE (the default) corresponds to the user's workspace (the global environment) and TRUE to the environment from which source is called.")

Comment: @docendodiscimus I did ?source before posting, and tried using the `local`argument. It does not work as I would. I guess the reason is that the global environment and the "environment from which source is called" are exactly the same. Thank you for pointing out anyway.

Comment: @akrun it WORKS! Thank you, :).  If you post an answer, I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to call a R script and run it. One of them would be `source()`.

Source evaluates the r script and does so in a certain environment if called so.
Say we have a `Test.R` script:

```
#Test.R
a <- 1    
rm(list = ls())
b <- 2
c <- 3
```

and global variables:

```
a <- 'a'
b <- 'b'
c <- 'c'
```

Now you would like to run this script, but in a certain environment not involving the global environment you are calling the script from. You can do this by doing creating a new environment and then calling `source`:

```
step1 <- new.env(parent = baseenv())

#Working directory set correctly.
source("Test.R", local = step1)
```

These are the results after the run, as you can see, the symbols in the global environment are not deleted.

```
a
#"a"
b
#"b"
step1$a
#NULL
#rm(list = ls()) actually ran in Test.R
step1$b
#2
```

Note:
You can also run a R script by using `system`. This will, however, be ran in a different R process and you will not be able to retrieve anything from where you called the script.

```
system("Rscript Test.R")
```

Answer (score 2):

We create the `new.env`

```
e1 <- new.env()
```

and use `sys.source` to source the R script with `envir` specifying as the 'e1' above

```
sys.source("step1.R", envir=e1)
```